# How to fetch column values using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask

I am using Flask+Python and to check if a **username** (and **email**) is already taken or not i am using this logic:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = SignupForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
      user = Users.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
      email = Users.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
      if form.username.data in user:
        error = 'Username already taken. Choose another'
      elif form.email.data in email:
        error = 'Email already registered. Login or register with another Email'
      else:
          user = Users( 
          form.username.data,
          form.password.data,
          #form.confirm.data ,
          form.email.data,
          1,
          # form.cityaddress.data,
          # form.countryaddress.data,
          #form.accept_tos.data,
      )
      db.session.add(user)
      db.session.commit()
      return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

But its giving error like `object has no attribute 'username'`

I know my logic for fetching data from db is not correct. I have little knowledge of SQLalchemy.

Could you suggest me How can i fetch `Username` (and `Email`) column value from table `Users` and then check them if there are same as `form.username.data` ?

Comment: Can you please paste the exact error, including the line that errors out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your queries look fine, the return value from `first()` will be an instance of your User object, or `None` if there were no results:

```
  u = Users.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
  if u is not None:
      print u.username
      print u.email
```

So given that, here's what your logic could look like:

```
  user_by_name = Users.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
  user_by_email = Users.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
  if user_by_name:
    error = 'Username already taken. Choose another'
  elif user_by_email:
    error = 'Email already registered. Login or register with another Email'
  else:
      #Unique user and email
```

You could also do it in one query:

```
 existing = Users.query.filter((Users.username == form.username.data) | (Users.email == form.email.data)).all()
 if existing:
     error = 'User or email taken'
```

Note the use of `filter` rather than `filter_by` - you cant use the bitwise operators in `filter_by`. Here's a quick [working example](https://gist.github.com/DazWorrall/5325897)

Answer (score 1):

Your error confuses me. That said, your code looks okayish, except for the test. I use this then:

```
user = Users.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
...
if user is not None:
    error("user already found")
```